# call of javascript function to external url always blocked by cors

Tags: functions, javascript

I created a `javascript function` that have to be called every time someone clicks a `button`. This is the code present on file `/wp-includes/js/utm.js`:

```
function event_click() {
    document.getElementById("cf_submit-site-aa7bccxxxx").addEventListener("click", prepareData2DB);
    console.log("ready");
}

function prepareData2DB() {
        // prepare body to send request 
        visitant = ...;
        send2DB(visitant);
    }
}

function send2DB(visitant) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log('response:' + this.response);
        }
    };

    xmlHttp.open("POST", "https://xyz.com.br/", true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(visitant));
}
```

This `file` is imported on `footer.php`:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/wp-includes/js/utm.js"></script>
```

When the `button` is clicked and the `function` triggered, I got this `error` on `console`:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xyz.com.br/'
>   from origin 'https://wordpress-host.com.br' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource

I already added this code on `functions.php`:

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

And using both https://corsproxy.github.io/ and https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ on call with the xyz url, I got:

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Last, I used [this](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cors/) plugin, but neither worked.

I don't know what else I can do to transpass this error.

Comment: Did you enable CORS on the *resource* (the `xyz.com.br` site)?

Comment: @SallyCJ, I didnt enabled, however, I tried to call a mocky.io url and got the same error. I think that is something on wordpress site

Comment: Sorry (about my previous comment, which I've deleted), I wasn't aware `mocky.io` is not a CORS proxy. But if you still get the CORS error with mocky.io, then the issue is with your *browser* and not WordPress. I mean, inside your `send2DB()`, try replacing the `https://xyz.com.br/` with `https://www.mocky.io/v2/5e7ed796300000da134afba0` - does it work? What's in the console?

Comment: @SallyCJ, thanks for your response. actually, it worked with your mocky.io. this helped me to better investigate what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put `cors header` on `functions.php`, allow cors on `API`, ensure `https` on both sides and allow `cors` on `digital ocean` – that hosts both `wordpress` and `API`